# error after compilation in C

Tags: c

```
if ((pos < n) && (key == ptr->keys[pos].value))
  {
    struct return_values* function(&ptr->keys[pos]);
  }
```

while compilation i get the error

```
 error: syntax error before '&' token in this line 
 struct return_values* function(&ptr->keys[pos]);
```

i am passing the address of ptr->keys[pos] to the function

```
struct return_values* function(struct classifier fun_ptr)
```

where struct return_values is the return type   what is the error here h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result of functon to a variable:

```
struct return_values* values = function(&ptr->keys[pos]);
```

Comment: i changed the it to function(&(ptr->keys[pos])); but now i get an error  error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `function' how to change my function declaration so that i can send the address to it

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling function from there, you don't need to write "struct return_values*" part.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> struct return_values* function(struct classifier fun_ptr)

to

> struct return_values* function(struct classifier *fun_ptr)